# I am getting below error the HTTP POST the Apex in salesforce

Tags: salesforce1-app

> Error: {"error":"unsupported_grant_type","error_description":"grant
>   type not supported"}

Code:

```
String username     = '****@gmail.com';
String password     = '***********WwmQ***';
String endPoint     = 'https://test.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token';
String clientid  = '****************';
String clientsecret = '****************8';
Http http = new Http();
HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
req.setEndpoint(endPoint);
req.setMethod('POST');
req.setHeader('Content-Type','application/json');
req.setBody('grant_type=password'+'&client_id='+clientid+'&client_secret='+clientsecret +'&username='+username+'&password='+password);
HttpResponse res = http.send(req);
System.debug('Body ' + res.getStatusCode());
```

Comment: You have the wrong `Content-Type`, you should be using `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`

Comment: i changed the Content-Type but still it is not working

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are not appending security token to your password string.

Please check below article from Salesforce.

> You must append the user’s security token to their password A security token is an automatically-generated key from Salesforce. For example, if a user's password is mypassword, and their security token is XXXXXXXXXX, then the value provided for this parmeter must be mypasswordXXXXXXXXXX. For more information on security tokens see “Reset Your Security Token” in the online help.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/intro_understanding_username_password_oauth_flow.htm

Comment: In Password i have given "Reset security token" of the user